# Should I use one-to-many or many-to-many to log previous records?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 2 tables, company and interns. the initial relationships are,

- An intern belongs to only one company.
- A company has many interns

I have a slight problem with these relationships.

If the student changes to another company halfway through but needs the record of the previous company to be kept, is it correct if I change the relationship to become 'An intern belongs to many company' and create a third table to handle the 'many-to-many' relationship?

Or should I just leave it at that and instead create a 'log' table that logs the students' previous company?

Or is there a better way?

Note : Imagine that this system requires the most efficient way of storing data and that student cannot belong to two or more different companies at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is `many-to-many` relationship exists in this case as the `Intern` will always be associated with a single company.

I would prefer to go with say a `LOG` (or `InternCompanyHistory`) table to save `InternId`, `CompanyId` and `DateOfChange` or any other attributes associated with change of company.